# WSO2 XACML Basic Policy Editor - Empty Choices

Tags: wso2, editor, identity, xacml

at Home -> Entitlement -> PAP -Policy Administration -> Basic XACML Editor

Error:  The Action tools icon does not show any choices (just a blank field), its empty. This happens on a fresh install of the server.

The same type of error also happens at "User Role" selection, a text field 
named "Enter Attribute Search Pattern" which shows a blank value.

I expected here to see a pre filled value like "http://*hostname*/claims/role" as shown in the screen-copy of the example described in article, here: 
http://xacmlinfo.org/2012/05/02/xacml-policy-editor-in-wso2-identity-server/

Please send an updated instruction for use of the Basic Policy Editor 
on WSO2 identity server Version 5 showing an example how to define and configure a basic XACML rule.

Thanks in advance for your support.

Below as attachment, you see a hardcopy of the issue at the WSO2 Standard Editor when using Attributes from the Extension section.

Enclosure: [Policy Editor Customization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXxBs.png)

[image: Rule Standard Editor - Add Attribute from PIP]

Comment: The WSO2 editor is buggy. Look through Stackoverflow and you'll see for yourself. Try the ALFA plugin for Eclipse or the Axiomatics Policy Editor instead.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this error. Will you please attach the screen shot here?